# Populate listView from sqlite data with AsyncTask

Tags: sqlite, android-listview, android-asynctask

I'm new to android and i know only some few stuffs. I need to learn more. I'm using `AsyncTask` for my Listview. I'm populating my listview with data from sqlite database. The problem here is that the Listview items cannot be displayed. It always just display the progress dialog and it's not getting any data behind it. I don't know what's wrong with the code. I don't know where I'm wrong here.

Db method

```
public List<Sport> getSports() {

            List<Sport> list = new ArrayList<Sport>();

            Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM sports", null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

                Sport s = new Sport();
                s.setId(cursor.getString(0));
                s.setSport(cursor.getString(1));

                list.add(s);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close();
            return list;
     }
```

On my onCreate method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            search_view = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);

            new MyAsynch().execute();

}
```

Adapter class

```
 private class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Sport>  {

            private ArrayList<Sport> originalList;
            private ArrayList<Sport> objects;

            public Adapter(Context context, List<Sport> objects) {
                super(context, 0, objects);

                this.objects = new ArrayList<Sport>();
                this.objects.addAll(objects);
                this.originalList = new ArrayList<Sport>();
                this.originalList.addAll(objects);

            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sports, parent, false);
                }

                TextView id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id);
                TextView sport = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sport);

                Sport s = sports.get(position);
                id.setText(s.getId());
                sport.setText(s.getSport());

                return convertView;
            }
     }
```

AsyncTask Class

```
  private class MyAsynch extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
         super.onPreExecute();
            pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pd.setMessage("Loading ...");
            pd.setIndeterminate(false);
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void...strings) { // run time intensive task in separate thread

                    databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                    databaseAccess.open();
                    sportsList = databaseAccess.getSports();
                    databaseAccess.close();

                    return null;
                }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        // Give the data to you adapter from here,instead of the place where you gave it earlier
            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            adapter = new Adapter(this, sportsList );
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            pd.dismiss();
        }
  }
```

Comment: are you receiving data in sportsList inside doInBackground method ?

Comment: @robodev There is no data inside. Normally there is data when i don't use AsyncTask process.

Comment: Log the cursor data in getSports method and check if the cursor contains any data

Comment: @robodev It's display a lot of com.sports.app12214. Something like that

Comment: I don't know what you did, inside the loop in getSports method write Log.e("tag", cursor.getString(1)); check whether it prints something

Comment: @robodev what it prints are like the package name with some numbers after it. Like this: "com.sports@14213 com.sports@14213 com.sports@14213". Lot's of like that stuff in my Log. Why is that?

Comment: It displays the address not the values.. Please try to print its values. Or put a break point inside the loop and check the cursor values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem i think is this:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        // Give the data to you adapter from here,instead of the place where you gave it earlier
            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            adapter = new Adapter(this, sportsList );
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            pd.dismiss();
        }
```

in the line adapter = new Adapter(this, sportsList);
when you send this, you are sending the asyctask context, and thats one problem.

Should be:

```
    adapter = new Adapter(getApplicationContext(), sportsList );
```

make that change and tell me then if it give some error.

Regards